# How to delete key value pair of a dictionary inside a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
dicto = {12:{34:45,56:78},45:{67:23,90:15}}
```

I want to delete a key value pair say `67:23` of the key `45` of the dictionary.How do I do it?

This is what I did so far but I get error

```
dicto = {12:{34:45,56:78},45:{67:23,90:15}}
for k,v in dicto.items():
    for i in v.keys():
        if i == 67:
            del v[i]

print(dicto)
```

The error that I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/Sublime-text programs/TestCode.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i in v.keys():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

How do I delete the particular key value pair?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Here I have a dictionary inside a dictionary and so I am unable to apply the regular delete method

Comment: you can use pop() - see answer. You will delete the key from ALL inner dicts because you iterate over all inner dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or to stay closer to what you did and delete the key 67 from all inner dictionaries without needing to know theire keys as well:

**will work for python 2.7**

```
dicto = {12:{34:45,56:78},45:{67:23,90:15}}
print ""
for k,v in dicto.items(): 
    for i in v.items():
         if (i[0] == 67):
                v.pop(i[0])
print(dicto)
```

Output:

```
{12: {56: 78, 34: 45}, 45: {90: 15}}
```

Instead of modifying some element you tell the correct inner dict to remove its key/value pair from itself

This code will remove the key ``67` from ALL inner dictionaries:

```
dicto = {12:{34:45,56:78},45:{67:23,90:15},99:{67:1,88:5}}
```

will lead to

```
{99: {88: 5}, 12: {56: 78, 34: 45}, 45: {90: 15}}
```

Edit:
As Souvik Rey pointed out, this wont work for 3.6 (tested it with pyfiddle for 2.7 where it works)

**will work with 3.6**

```
dicto = {12:{34:45,56:78},45:{67:23,90:15},99:{67:1,88:5}}
print ("")
dictsToRemoveKeysFrom = []
for k,v in dicto.items():
    print (v)
    for i in v.items():
         if (i[0] == 67):
                dictsToRemoveKeysFrom.append(v)

for d in dictsToRemoveKeysFrom:
    d.pop(67)

print(dicto)
```

You get the error because you alter the dictionarys while iterating over theire parent. Simply remember the dicts to modify and modify them afterwards.

Comment: First you are missing out that .items() gives two iterators and so it will  throw an error that object is not subscriptable since i is an int and you are trying to access i[0]

Comment: @SouvikRay Sorry, my www.pyfiddle.io sat on python 2.7 where this works. The 2nd version will work for 3.6.

Comment: @SouvikRay `items()` will give 2 items, but if I use it like here , `i` will be a tuple and I can access it with `i[0]` no problem. To avoid the error simply remember the dictionarys to modify and modify them out of the iteration

Comment: Yep now it works just fine.That's actually a good idea to store the dictionary in a seperate list and then the methods like pop and del can be used directly on it.Yes you are right. items() returns a tuple and so i[0] can actually be used.Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple enough.

```
>>> dicto = {12:{34:45,56:78},45:{67:23,90:15}}
>>> dicto
{12: {34: 45, 56: 78}, 45: {67: 23, 90: 15}}
>>> del dicto[45][67]
>>> dicto
{12: {34: 45, 56: 78}, 45: {90: 15}}
```

Comment: for this you need to know the 45 though - his solution would remove this key from any innner dictionary, wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

It is simplyer as it looks, no for needed :

```
del k[45][63]
```

Comment: for this you need to know the 45 though - his solution would remove this key from any innner dictionary, wouldnt it?